# Как максимально быстро записать вектор в файл

Tags: c++, файлы, c++11, vector, байты

Собственно есть вектор `std::vector<unsigned char> outputdata`
Есть файл в папке с программой `output.txt`

---

Как максимально быстро можно записать вектор в файл так, чтобы 1й байт файла соответствовал первому элементу `outdata[0]`, последний - последнему `outdata[56871]`.

Comment: Использовать native OS функцию записи. Например, в \*nix-ах `write(out_file_descr, &ouputdata[0], outputdata.size())`

Comment: @avp будет ли это быстрее ofstream? Если да - то на сколько?

Comment: Быстрее, на время пересылки байт из вектора в буфер ofstream. В секундах измерьте  сами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что вот так:

```
ofstream out(имя_файла, ios::binary);
...    
out.write((char*)outputdata.data(),outputdata.size());
```

Если, конечно, вы хотите именно байт в байт, а не, скажем, писать байты из вектора как десятичные числа в текстовом представлении.

Comment: А разве не нужно открывать с флагом binary?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG А это не очевидно? ну, сейчас допишу...